# PostgreSQL - Calculate SUM() of COUNT()

Tags: postgresql

Basically I have a table called `cities` which looks like this:

```
+------+-----------+---------+----------+----------------+
| id   | name      | lat     | lng      | submitted_by   |
|------+-----------+---------+----------+----------------|
| 1    | Pyongyang | 39.0392 | 125.7625 | 15             |
| 2    | Oslo      | 59.9139 | 10.7522  | 8              |
| 3    | Hebron    | 31.5326 | 35.0998  | 8              |
| 4    | Hebron    | 31.5326 | 35.0998  | 10             |
| 5    | Paris     | 48.8566 | 2.3522   | 12             |
| 6    | Hebron    | 31.5326 | 35.0998  | 7              |
+------+-----------+---------+----------+----------------+
```

Desired result:

```
+-----------+---------+
| name      | count   |
|-----------+---------|
| Hebron    | 3       |
| Pyongyang | 1       |
| Oslo      | 1       |
| Paris     | 1       |
| Total     | 6       | <-- The tricky part
+-----------+---------+
```

In other words, what I need to do is `SELECT` the `SUM` of the `COUNT` in the query I'm currently using:
`SELECT name, count(name)::int FROM cities GROUP BY name;`

But apparently nested aggregated functions are not allowed in PostgreSQL. I'm guessing I need to use `ROLLUP` in some way but I can't seem to get it right.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: rollup works on very group, add a UNION of thetotalcount

Comment: @nbk UNION sounds like a good idea but I can't see how it can be used if I still can't access the COUNT. Here's what I'm getting: `HINT:  There is a column named "count" in table "*SELECT* 1", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oh, thanks for pointing out, it's just a typo. Fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to UNION ALL the total sum.

WITH ROLLUP works by summing up the total for every group separate and can't be used here.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE cities (
>   "id" INTEGER,
>   "name" VARCHAR(9),
>   "lat" FLOAT,
>   "lng" FLOAT,
>   "submitted_by" INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO cities
>   ("id", "name", "lat", "lng", "submitted_by")
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'Pyongyang', '39.0392', '125.7625', '15'),
>   ('2', 'Oslo', '59.9139', '10.7522', '8'),
>   ('3', 'Hebron', '31.5326', '35.0998', '8'),
>   ('4', 'Hebron', '31.5326', '35.0998', '10'),
>   ('5', 'Paris', '48.8566', '2.3522', '12'),
>   ('6', 'Hebron', '31.5326', '35.0998', '7');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT name, COUNT(name)::int FROM cities GROUP BY name
> UNION ALL 
> SELECT 'Total', COUNT(*) FROM cities
> ```
>
> ```
> name      | count
> :-------- | ----:
> Hebron    |     3
> Pyongyang |     1
> Oslo      |     1
> Paris     |     1
> Total     |     6
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=cfa3130839360fd94a81cef767a36070)*

Comment: I've tried this but it seems to me that the second SELECT is completely unrelated the first query, for example as soon as you add an "HAVING" to the first query (`HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`) the total doesn't match (it is still 6, not 3).

Comment: Having males no sense, as the sum I. The second query only returned nacone value the total sum of all values above. Ease make a ne question with table data and wanted result to see what can be done

Comment: Sorry to insist, but I think it does makes sense (if I'm getting what you wrote, what "nacone" means?), OP said what he wanted was to "SELECT the SUM of the COUNT in **the query I'm currently using**", this isn't using his query, it is querying the DB _regardless_ the result of that, since that's exactly what I'm trying to achieve I was interested exactly in this feature, but I will create a new question as advised.

Comment: As I said make a new question and add data to it  , if you oblx wyntt to count the selected data , make first a CTE that select all data the make the above query with the CTE, that is simple and would give the result, so the answer is correct for this Szenario

Answer (score 2):

While the wanted result seems simple to achieve with `UNION ALL` as shown in the accepted answer, I think we should take into account any changes to the main query, so that the `total` would depend on it instead of just counting all cities (which is basically like running two independent queries), like mentioned into the question what we want is **the SUM of the COUNT**.

This query will take into account the main one into the sum:

```
WITH city_counts AS (
  SELECT name, COUNT(*)::int AS count
  FROM cities
  GROUP BY name
  HAVING COUNT(*) < 3 <---------- we only want the cities repeated less than 3 times
)
SELECT name, count
FROM city_counts
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Total', SUM(count)
FROM city_counts;
```

If we run it against the table in question, we'll get

```
+-----------+---------+
| name      | count   |
|-----------+---------|
| Pyongyang | 1       |
| Oslo      | 1       |
| Paris     | 1       |
| Total     | 3       |
+-----------+---------+
```

`Hebron` won't be listed as `<3`, and the total (`3`) is the sum of each city `COUNT(*)` given by the main query, without `Hebron`.